# Mockito / PowerMocktio doNothing for none void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I need a method which returns something to do nothing when invoked during testing, the class instance which owns the method is implemented as a spy.

I am aware the doNothing() method only works with void methods. Is there a way to get the same  behaviour with a method that returns something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `when(spy.myMethod()).thenReturn(null)`. This will prevent the spy from invoking the wrapped instance. You have to tell Mockito what to return for a method that returns something. The default behavior for a `mock` is to return `null`. The default behavior for a `spy` is to call the wrapped object. When you `stub` a method in a `spy` it prevents the call to the wrapped object and executes the specified behavior.

Per documents of [Spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html), you could also do `doReturn(null).when(spy).myMethod();`

Comment: Yes this works! Can't believe how simple that was :)

Comment: Note that `when(spy.myMethod()).thenReturn(null)` does not work (in the general case, it might in a specific case) for a spy because the method's actual implementation will be executed at this point. The general rule is that spies must always be stubbed with the `doXyz().when(spy).method()` syntax to prevent accidental execution of the real code.