# Non-void method with doNothing() in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, google-cloud-platform, mockito, google-cloud-storage

I have a unit test to test uploading a file to GCP storage. Here is the code for upload the file.

```
@Override
public boolean upload(StorageConfiguration storageConfiguration, File file) throws MetaFeedException {
    // get google storage connection.
    Optional<Storage> storage = getStorageConnection(storageConfiguration.getJsonCredentialFilePath());

    // if GCP storage is empty, return empty.
    if (!storage.isPresent()) {
        throw new MetaFeedException("Failed to establish connection with GCP storage");
    }

    // upload blob with given file content
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(storageConfiguration.getBucketName(),
            storageConfiguration.getBucketPath().concat(file.getName()));
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(storageConfiguration.getContentType()).build();
    try {
        return storage.get().create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()))).exists();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MetaFeedException("Error occurred while uploading file.", e);
    }
}
```

In my unit tests, I've done something like this,

```
@Test
public void should_upload_file_to_gcp_with_given_data() throws Exception {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("file-name", "1");

    StorageConfiguration storageConfiguration = new StorageConfiguration();
    storageConfiguration.setBucketName("sample-bucket");
    storageConfiguration.setBucketPath("ff/");
    storageConfiguration.setJsonCredentialFilePath("json-credentials");
    storageConfiguration.setContentType("text/plain");

    StorageOptions defaultInstance = mock(StorageOptions.class);
    Storage mockStorage = spy(Storage.class);

    when(defaultInstance.getService()).thenReturn(mockStorage);

    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(storageConfiguration.getBucketName(), storageConfiguration.getBucketPath().concat(tempFile.getName()));
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(storageConfiguration.getContentType()).build();

    doNothing().when(mockStorage).create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tempFile.getAbsolutePath())));

    boolean upload = gcpStorageManager.upload(storageConfiguration, tempFile);
    Assert.assertTrue(upload);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is prevent calling the `create()` method. My point is I don't want to perform a real upload to GCP since it's a test. So I tried as above. But I got an error,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
 Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception 
the 2nd time is called
```

**UPDATE**

```
Optional<Storage> storage;
    try {
        //connect with the json key file if the key path is not empty
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(jsonCredentialFilePath) && Files.exists(Paths.get(jsonCredentialFilePath))) {
            storage = Optional.ofNullable(StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonCredentialFilePath)))
                    .build().getService());
        } else {
            // if no json key file provided connect to storage without key file.
            storage = Optional.ofNullable(StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MetaFeedException("Error occurred while connecting to GCP storage", e);
    }

    return storage;
```

Is there a way to fix this test for uploading file to GCP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the following problem:
I had a method that was returning a Page<...> ,but I can use doNothing() only on void method ,so the fix is easy:

```
    @Override
    public Page<ThreadServiceModel> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return this.findAll(ThreadServiceModel.class, pageable);
    }
```

And here we go:

```
        //Will fail and the actualy findAll will be invoked:
        when(this.threadServices.findAll(ThreadServiceModel.class,pageable)).thenReturn(null);

        //Will fail ,cuz you cannot call doNothing() on something that returns values

        doNothing().when(this.threadServices).findAll(ThreadServiceModel.class,pageable);

        //This is the solution ,and when you use doReturn() the actual method will be NOT invoked,
        //+In my case i dont need value , but if i want I cant use...
        doReturn(null).when(this.threadServices).findAll(ThreadServiceModel.class,pageable);
```

So the solution is simple ,use the last method on the code that I have showed you :)

Comment: If I don't want to return null coz its throwing null pointer

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is described in the error message: `Only void methods can doNothing()`

The `create()` method is not void, so you cannot mock it with `doNoting()` so you have to use `doReturn` instead. In you case you can return a mock of `Blob`:

```
Blob mockBlob = mock(Blob.class);
when(mockBlob.exists()).thenReturn(true);
doReturn(mockBlob).when(mockStorage).create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tempFile.getAbsolutePath())));
```

This is the first mistake. And the second, it looks like you are not injecting the spied object into you object-under-test.
Your method `getStorageConnection()` will create a new instance of `Storage` when you call it and does not take into account the spied object.
So you are mocking the `StorageOptions.class` but the `StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance()` method don't know anything about this mocked object.

So here I can see two paths to fixing your problem. The first one, and it's a more preferable one as for me is to inject dependency either to a method or to your class.
Dependency injection to method:

```
@Override
public boolean upload(Storage storage, File file) throws MetaFeedException {
```

But this may not be the case, as long as your method overrides some interface, as I assume. So you can move your method `getStorageConnection` to a separate class `StorageProvider` and inject the instance of it to you class, and then in the test you can mock a `StorageProvider` to return a `spy` of a `Storage`. In the upload method you will call:

```
Optional<Storage> storage = storageProvider.getStorageConnection(storageConfiguration.getJsonCredentialFilePath());
```

The second path, which is rather workaround is to make the method `getStorageConnection` protected, and the override it in your test to return a spied object. In your test:

```
gcpStorageManager = new GcpStorageManager() {
  @Override
  protected Storage getStorageConnection(...) {
    return mockedStorage;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden` I got this because it's still trying to upload the file.

Comment: Does the method `create()` return `Blob` or `Bucket`. You have to be sure that you stub the needed method not an overloaded one.

Comment: it's returning a blob.

Comment: Are you sure that the spied `storage` is the same as the one used in the method?

Comment: And also, do you really need a `spy` here? Why not to use `mock`?

Comment: In implementation method, it's in an `Optional<Storage>`. But the create method should get called right. I used spy() instead of mock() because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018330/mockito-powermocktio-donothing-for-none-void-method something mentioned here

Comment: Yes, I see that this is `Optional<Storage>` but does `Optional` holds an instance of your `spy` object? Can you show the code of `getStorageConnection`?

Comment: Updated the question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184870/discussion-between-codebot-and-sergii-bishyr).

Comment: Have extended my answer. Check it and see if you have any questions